Where to run digitalocean's `do-release-upgrade`? Getting "run over SSH" warning
I'm attempting to do maintenance on an older server I have running on Digital Ocean, and I'm having a hard time finding best practices for how to upgrade Ubuntu versions. I did find Digital Ocean's own upgrade guides, which suggest that, after updating and upgrading all plugins and dependencies to run Ubuntu's upgrade command, do-release-upgrade.
However when I run it over SSH, I get the following warning:
Continue running under SSH? 

This session appears to be running under ssh. It is not recommended 
to perform a upgrade over ssh currently because in case of failure it 
is harder to recover. 

If you continue, an additional ssh daemon will be started at port 
'1022'. 
Do you want to continue? 

Continue [yN] 

So I thought, since I was SSHed into the server through my local terminal, maybe I need to do it through the console that's accessible through Digital Ocean's server dashboard. However, when I try to run it there, it's still being run through SSH and gives me the same warning.
They don't mention this in the upgrade documentation and I don't see it googling around, so where is the proper place to run this do-release-upgrade command to mitigate these SSH concerns?
Thanks!

It just tells you that if you have the choice, do it local because the recovery from errors is easier there. You don't have this choice, ignore the misplaced warning.
It's also dating back from the era where do-release-upgrade was failing more often than it was working. Now, it has lost its purpose.
